# How to disable read-only recommended when opening Word document through Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, readonly

I have this subroutine below which opens a Word document from Excel.

```
Sub openword()

Set WordApp = CreateObject("word.Application")
    WordApp.documents.Open Filename:="C:..."      'File name
   
    WordApp.Visible = True

    
End Sub
```

However, every time I run it, it opens the word doc in "read-only" mode. I have tried everything to disable this, including:

```
ReadOnly=False
```

but have so far been unsuccessful.

It is apparently a Microsoft recognized issue for which they suggest the following solution: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/word-document-opens-as-read-only-when-you-try-to-programmatically-open-the-document-4cab20a5-89f5-9834-9c66-247076cb72e8

Unfortunately, I am not sure how to implement it in my code without running into errors.
I have tried this:

```
Sub openword()


Set WordApp = CreateObject("word.Application")
    WordApp.documents.Open Filename:="C:...."
   
    WordApp.Visible = True
    
WordBasic.FileOpen Name:="C:..."

    
End Sub
```

and `WordBasic.FileOpen Name:="C:..."`returns a
"Run-time error '424':
Object required"

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: So how did you apply the update and which line then gave the error?

Comment: @Solar Mike I tried to insert this line at the bottom of my subroutine like so: ` WordBasic.FileOpen Name:="C:..." `

Comment: So show the code and error detail in the question.

Comment: @SolarMike, please see edit in post.

Answer (score 1):

The link you shared shows exactly how to use it. Put the parameter after the filename.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub openword()
    Dim WordApp As Object
    Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    WordApp.documents.Open Filename:="C:...", ReadOnly:=False         
    WordApp.Visible = True 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

`WordBasic.FileOpen Name:="C:..."` generates an error because you are running the code from Excel and Excel does not have a `WordBasic` object.

Replace it with `WordApp.WordBasic.FileOpen Name:="C:..."` and it may work, though as Word Basic is essentially deprecated (it was the macro language before VBA) it may not.